# meteor cordova build vs production server (no hot code push)

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor

can't get my head around hot code push in my setup:

on server A (osx with xcode and add-platform ios) i built a meteor cordova app with

```
meteor run ios-device --mobile-server https://productionserver.com
```

(when i point my cordova app at my localhost:3000 hot code push is working just fine).

on server B (linux, nginx, some meteor instances on port 808x) i run

```
meteor --port=127.0.0.1:8080
```

server B runs without add-platform ios (linux), but i found an interesting discussion from slava [here](https://www.marshut.net/ksvrwk/mobile-app-hot-code-update-issues-in-production.html) and did:

```
meteor add-platform firefoxos
```

and thought that hot code push would trigger with this stub.

when i change the code (client directory) on server B, the change is reflected when i call the web interface.

**But in my cordova app no change is happening even after app restart.**

can you please point me in the right direction?

how is the code push happening behind the scenes?

how should i set up my build/prod environment the make hot code push working?

thanks for your help

Comment: did you ever find a solution? Battling with this issue myself.

Comment: unfortunately not yet.

Comment: Have you tried http instead of https? I have the same problem with my android hot code push. It works on http, but not on https.

Answer (score 0):

I got my app working. The problem was that I had removed android from the platforms list. I'm guessing you still have ios in your platforms.

Your Meteor setup strikes me as a little odd:
1. you say you have multiple Meteor instances on port 8080? 
2. Also starting Meteor on a specific port uses command `meteor --port 8080` and not the IP.
3. Does the app actually connect to the server? As in databases get synced and new information gets sent across?